# Can we use IIF to dynamically select the datepart argument to dateadd?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use `iif` inside `datediff`. Is it possible? I tried the below

```
SELECT DATEADD(IIF( 1>2, year, month), 1, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;
```

but got an error

> Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd.

Is this possible?

I tried the following solution, and it is working fine.

```
SELECT IIF( 1>2,  DATEADD(year, 1, '2017/08/25'), DATEADD(month, 1, '2017/08/25')) AS DateAdd;
```

But why can't we do the opposite, and is there any guide as to which function we can or can't use as a child or input to another function?

Comment: You *can*, but not there. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), the first parameter **must** be a literal from the list of allowable arguements, not an expression.

Comment: Because `year`, `month` is not an expression context part but rather part of the syntax, so it cannot be "expression"-ized

Comment: I guess in this case you could *probably* use `DATEADD(month, IIF( 1>2, 12, 1), '2017-08-25')` - unless there is some edge case where that would return something different!

Comment: And there is no such edge case https://dbfiddle.uk/tjZ6WbGA

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the first parameter, *datepart*, cannot be an expression, instead it must be a literal from the allowable list:

> The part of *date* to which `DATEADD` adds an **integer** *number*. This table lists all valid *datepart* arguments.
>
> | datepart | Abbreviations |
> | --- | --- |
> | year | yy, yyyy |
> | quarter | qq, q |
> | month | mm, m |
> | dayofyear | dy, y |
> | day | dd, d |
> | week | wk, ww |
> | weekday | dw, w |
> | hour | hh |
> | minute | mi, n |
> | second | ss, s |
> | millisecond | ms |
> | microsecond | mcs |
> | nanosecond | ns |

If you need to do this kind of logic, then you will need to implement the second method you used; you use an `IIF` function (`CASE` expression) and then have a `DATEADD` function in the true/false (`WHEN`/`ELSE`) sections with different values for the *datepart* parameter.

This requirement if true for many of the date (and time) functions, such as `DATEDIFF`, `DATETRUNC` and `DATE_BUCKET` (not an exhaustive list).